# Bootstrap 3 right-aligned nav affecting collapsed menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is when the collapsible menu appears (i.e. on mobile devices), the text is right-aligned.

Is there an alternative way to pull navigation to the right without affecting the collapsed version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `navbar-right` class instead of `pull-right`.

This is documented in [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment):

> Align nav links, forms, buttons, or text, using the .navbar-left or
>   .navbar-right utility classes. Both classes will add a CSS float in
>   the specified direction. [...]
>
> These classes are mixin-ed versions of .pull-left and .pull-right, but
>   they're scoped to media queries for easier handling of navbar
>   components across device sizes.

Comment: How'd I miss that?! Thanks.